# Convert Char[] to Int, war card game

Tags: c#

I am doing a card war game for school, my professor gave me some files `.txt` with cards and the problem that I am having is that I cant turn my 'A'(Ace), 'K'(King) to `int` so I can compare them with the other cards. I have tried everything but its not working out so I came here for any tip or help.

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)  
{
    StreamReader sr;
    try
    {
        sr = new StreamReader("JOG1.TXT");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Ficheiro Não existe!");
    }

    String linha1 = sr.ReadLine();
    String linha2 = sr.ReadLine();
    sr.Close();  

    if (linha1.Length!=16 || linha2.Length!=16)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Ficheiro Inválido");
    }
    char[] p1=linha1.ToCharArray();
    char[] p2=linha2.ToCharArray();

    if(p1[0] > p2[0]){
        Console.WriteLine("ganhou");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("perdeu");

        //Console.WriteLine(linha1);
        //Console.WriteLine(linha2);
        //Console.WriteLine(p1[5]);
        //Console.WriteLine(p2[5]);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an “'A'(Ace)” anywhere in your code.

Comment: Im using files .txt that my professor got, for example this : VDV7V66764475DD5
6ARAR7AR5RVD4A54

Comment: It's not clear from your code where you're actually parsing the lines, except where you compare the first character of the first two lines. It would be helpful if the code you showed actually matched your question, and if you provided sample input (in your question, not in the comments) and expected output. The short answer is, any character can be converted to an `int` by casting (`int ace = (int) 'A';`) or parsing (`int ace = int.Parse('A');`). But in order to provide a more meaningful answer, we'd need more information, like what do the two lines represent, and what do the characters mean?

Comment: they represent 2 decks of cards, A is for Ace and K is for King. i tried that code but it gives me the number in ASCII

Comment: I don't understand the txt files. What do V and D stand for? How do you represent the number 10 with one character?

Comment: You need to handle the values for A(ce), K(ing), Q(ueen), and J(ack) separately since Ace beats King (and all others) but K > A in ASCII/C#. The line `if (p1[0] > p2[0])` will not work for Jack-Ace.

Comment: yes i know Haldo, thats what i cant do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how to map a one-character representation of a card into a number that represents the card's rank.

The brute force way to do this would be to check for each value and return the rank:

```
public static int GetRank1(char card)
{
    switch (card)
    {
        case '2' : return 2;
        case '3' : return 3;
        case '4' : return 4;
        case '5' : return 5;
        case '6' : return 6;
        case '7' : return 7;
        case '8' : return 8;
        case '9' : return 9;
        case 'J' : return 11;
        case 'Q' : return 12;
        case 'K' : return 13;
        case 'A' : return 14;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But a more clever way would be to arrange the characters in order in a string and use their position as the rank:

```
public static int GetRank2(char card)
{
    const string ranks = "23456789JQKA";
    return ranks.IndexOf(card);
}
```

You will have to modify the above if your representations are different, e.g. if you use V or D instead of J, Q, or K. You will also have to add an item that represents a 10-card.

Comment: And you need some special character for `'10'`, perhaps the roman numeral `'X'`?

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: Sounds like you should post another question (after doing a search).

Comment: nevermind, i was puting it in the wrong place, its working well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it as in int:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = 'A';
        Console.WriteLine($"The integer value of {c} is {(int)c}");

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert strings to ints by using the `int.Parse()` function.

Comment: `int.Parse("A")` will throw `65`

Comment: int.Parse("A") will throw an exception. You can't convert 'A' to int using int.Parse().

Comment: You can do `int.Parse('A')`, or simply `(int) 'A'`, which will return `65`.